# Receive event on uninstalling iPhone app

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to receive event/notification in my app when user uninstall my application from iPhone?

I need this because i want to clean up some data from address book while user uninstall my app.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not get the opportunity to execute any code when they choose to uninstall your app.

If there is data you add to the address book that you think they may wish to remove, then you should probably provide a way for them to do so, perhaps on a settings page inside your app.  The user could be warned to "only remove this data if you intend to uninstall the app" or something like that.

Better still, since the user could always arbitrarily change data in their address book at a future time, and perhaps break your application, a *much better* practice would be to store any app-related data in the documents directory created automatically for your app, in a plist or sqlite format for example.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that is not possible. What data are you storing data in address book?

Answer (score 0):

They can always re-install your app, so add an option in the app for them to clean all app related data out of the address book.  Then they could reinstall, clean, and delete again if they felt it was an issue.

Or, sell a separate $3 cleaning app if you are feeling evil.