# Is there any reliable way to determine if an app has been uninstalled on a device?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Basically I want to clear a user's "session" on the server when the app is deleted from a device. Is there any reliable way to figure this out?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291054/receive-event-on-uninstalling-iphone-app

Short answer: no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app implements push notification Apple server will inform you when you try to push to an uninstalled instance. 
Other than that - no.

Comment: Just read the section on the Feedback Service in APNS documentation. Thanks for the heads-up!