# How to know if our app is installed from iOS Device?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get notified when our app is uninstalled in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781203/how-to-get-notified-when-our-app-is-uninstalled-in-ios)

- Let me know any method to handle it when app is will or did uninstall.
- Any **setting** when resume of application to if its uninstall then notify or alert **"Sure You want uninstall application ?"** with option YES-NO.

Comment: Answer not there for same question ?

Comment: What part of "No, it's impossible" do you not understand?

Comment: @KurtRevis : Do you got any solution let me know ? Waiting for your ANSWERED reply!! "Nothing is Impossible"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)**. Let me know any method to handle it when app is will or did uninstall.

No, there is no such method.

**2)**. Any setting when resume of application to if its uninstall then notify or alert "Sure You want uninstall application ?" with option YES-NO.

iOS always ask user to weather they want to delete app or cancel.

Comment: I want handle that delete button action or create same popup from our application.

Comment: Sorry.... You can not...

Answer (score 0):

This feature already exists in iOS device. Whenever you go ahead and uninstall the application. First of all when you uninstall the application it is nothing but you Delete it. When user delete any application device does give the alert "Do you want to delete this application" with option "Delete" and "Cancel". You don't have to write any specific code for this.

There is one method in which you can find out when user is about to delete your app. That is you need to implement push notification Apple server will inform you when you try to push to an uninstalled instance. Other than that there's no way to detect it.

Comment: Ri8 now i am using APNS for my application. Can u specify that method where we can find out app is deleted.

Comment: @SARANG: i think you'll get it here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3